# How do I show the icons of Windows executable on OS X?

Tags: finder, snow-leopard, icon

Instead of the icons all showing up as the same for each .exe in Finder, is there a plugin or something that will let me see what the executable icons actually look like?

For example, .app on Finder has their own icons like this:

[image]

I want the .exe ones to also have their own icons depending on what program they are.

Comment: Windows .EXE's contain the icon file, you could extract it and save it to a file using a Windows machine and the program [resource hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Comment: I'm not after extracting the icons. I'm after actually showing them on OS X's Finder. I'm pretty sure I stumbled across a way to do that for Snow Leopard before but I can't remember what it was.

Answer (score -3):

This issue is resolved by updating to MacOS 10.12